# Magnesium mineralizer filter cartridge?

Tags: water, filter

I use a jug filter with BWT magnesium cartridges now and like the result.

I'm thinking of installing an under-counter filter instead, with a at least two stages, mechanical and carbon. But I'd want to add magnesium in a third (or fourth) stage, and I can't seem to find any magnesium mineralizer cartridges for 10 inch systems or something similar. There are "calcium and magnesium" remineralizer cartridges, but they seem to add far more calcium than magnesium, and I don't want the calcium as it might make the water too hard; I won't put reverse osmosis into the system so natural calcium will remain.

So, in what way could I add magnesium with an under-counter filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a four-step process.

Step 1 - Design your under-counter filtration system to handle all of your needs except the magnesium part.

In the following steps, **bold type** denotes exact search terms that you may put between quotation marks to find the products that I mention.

Step 2 - Purchase an additional **cartridge filter housing** that you will use for magnesium remineralization. In the U.S. a standard size uses 10-inch cartridges. Purchase an **empty refillable canister** of the same size as your filter housing. This will be installed in the filter housing after loading it with granular minerals. Purchase **granular magnesium oxide** and make sure it is NSF certified for drinking water. Purchase **magnesium test strips**.

Step 3 - Test the magnesium content of your filtered water without added magnesium.

Step 4 - Assemble your filter housing and filter cartridge loaded half-full of magnesium oxide granules and connect it to your filtration system. Run a few liters of water through it, then taste the water and test the magnesium content with your test strips. If you like the taste, congratulations, you are finished. If it tastes like it needs more magnesium, disassemble the filter housing and add more granules. Taste and measure again. If it tastes too mineral-y or bitter, reduce the depth of granules in the cartridge. Eventually you should find a taste and measurement that you like.

The granules will be consumed very slowly, as magnesium oxide is barely soluble in neutral pH water. You can test your filtered water for magnesium monthly or quarterly and add granules as needed. I would suggest sanitizing the filter housing and cartridge on whatever schedule is recommended by the manufacturer, and when you do, discard the old magnesium oxide granules and add fresh.

Comment: Thanks! One question I have is about the water that is in that final cylinder, under pressure, for hours while the tap is closed. Does this mean that a blast of high-magnesium water comes out of the tap when I open it? Too high magnesium might be a health hazard? Or there won't be very much because the dissolving rate is so slow?

Comment: @MikhailRamendik Just my opinion but I don't think so because magnesium oxide is nearly insoluble in neutral pH water, no matter how long it sits. If you have concerns, draw some water that has sat overnight in the filter housing and test it using your magnesium test strips.